# How to use pickle to save custom objects in python?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I have some lists, each has some custom objects. I want to save these objects and these lists. But when i use pickle to save, it seems to create new object for each object of lists even if this object is created before. How can i solve it, Thanks:)

Here is the demo:

```py
import pickle

class Test():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

test_obj = Test('aaa')

a = []
b = []
a.append(test_obj)
b.append(test_obj)
print(a[0] == b[0]) # True

with open('./test.bin', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(test_obj, f)
    pickle.dump(a, f)
    pickle.dump(b, f)

with open('./test.bin', 'rb') as f:
    test_obj = pickle.load(f)
    a = pickle.load(f)
    b = pickle.load(f)
    print(a[0] == b[0]) # False, I want True
```

Comment: Your problem is comparison, not pickling. The default equality is by identity,.

Comment: if you want this behavior you can just assign "a" to "b" instead of loading twice the same pickle, bu in your code "a" and "b" are already object from the same class with the same attributes. The comparison returns False just because they are different instances.